# In Python, if you have two lists that share a number of elements, how do you create a new list with the matches?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, match

If you have two lists that share a number of elements, how do you find the matches, and create a new list of these elements?

Ex.)

```
 first = ['cat','dog','parrot','fish']
 second = ['fish', 'hamster', 'mouse', 'dog']
```

how would make a function/for-loop that searches for the matches and puts them into a list?

```
 matches = ['dog', 'fish']
```

Comment: Does the order of items in the result matter?

Comment: You can convert them to set and perform and/intersection. like list(set(first) and set(second))

Answer (score 1):

You can do `set.intersection` if order does not matter:

```
list(set(first).intersection(second))
```

Or if order matters, you can do a list comprehension:

```
[x for x in first if x in second]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
match = []
for i in first:
    for j in second:
        if i == j:
            match.append(i)

print('Match: {}'.format(match))
```